# how to handle POJO class value that can either be null or integer

Tags: java, android, pojo

Here is the value as represented in the POJO class when it is null

```
  @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private Object parentId;
```

and when it is not

```
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private Integar parentId;
```

How can it be represented to avoid errors due to type mismatch

Comment: Why is it represented as Object and not represented as Integer when it is null?

Comment: I am using an online json to pojo  converter. is it wrong?